# USB Linux API: call ioctl requests from user space app

Tags: c, linux, usb, driver, ioctl

I want to create Linux app responsible to get/set some usb settings especially settings responsible of followings:

- USB ports
- USB Host controller and USB driver
- USB devices

I followed the linux api document: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/usb/usb.html I found that it can be done through ioctl
I found a list of ioctl requests, for example USBDEVFS_GETDRIVER.

I found that if I want a first small test it can be like that:

```
struct usbdevfs_getdriver usbdriver;
int fd = open("device_file_name", O_RDWR);
ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_GETDRIVER, (struct usbdevfs_getdriver*) &usbdriver);
```

Is that the right way? What should be the device_file_name in the second line of my code?

Answer (score 1):

The string `device_file_name` should be replaced with the path to a USB device node file.  The document you mentioned explains that the path to such a file looks like `/dev/bus/usb/BBB/DDD`.

You should check the values returned by both `open` and `ioctl` to see if the operations succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

The device_file_name: should be the file where usb is mounted. In general it is under /mnt/.
You can use command dmesg.